# How to use value of variables in expressions in R?

Tags: r, variables

I am relatively new to R. How do I use the value of variables in print and other statements. For example, in Java we can do this by:

```
System.out.println(" My name is "+ pradeep);
```

We use the + operator. How to do this in R?

Comment: Either use `paste` as Henrik stated, or use `c`, but handle with care. It really depends on type of data. `paste` should suffice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In R you can do this with `paste()` (see `?paste` for more info):

```
print(paste("My name is ", pradeep, ".", sep = ""))
```

Comment: Perhaps you meant `paste("My name is", pradeep)`?

Comment: Feels like `print()` is redundant.

Comment: print() is redundant at the command line. From within a function, you'll have to use it.

Answer (score 1):

In general you should prefer Henrik's answer, but note that you can specify strings with `sprintf`.

```
name <- c("Richie", "Pradeep")
sprintf("my name is %s", name)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming

```
pradeep <- "Pradeep"
```

Try this:

```
cat("My name is", pradeep, "\n")
```

Also the gsubfn package has the ability to add quasi perl-style string interpolation to any command by prefacing the command with `fn$`

```
library(gsubfn)
fn$cat("My name is $pradeep\n")

fn$print("My name is $pradeep")
```

There is also `sprintf` and `paste`, as mentioned by others.